# How could I set a minimum donation amount with paypal using advanced variables?

Tags: paypal, minimum

I was wondering how I would set up a donation button to place a minimum donation amount (So users can't donate $0.01 and place me $0.29 in debt each transaction. I found ways for shopping carts (which appear to be bypassable) and ways for dropdown menus. However, what I am looking for, is a way to give users flexible donation amounts but have a minimum amount of $1.00. Does anyone know how I could do this? I found a post saying it is possible with advanced variables and that I should ask this forum.

Comment: FYI, most payment processors will cap their fee at the amount of the transfer, so I don't think you can go into debt from 1 cent donations. (I don't know if Paypal does this, though.) If this is the case, just posting a message to the effect of "Please donate at least a dollar so your donation doesn't go entirely to Paypal" might be sufficient.

Comment: I don't believe paypal does this. I saw this same issue on many different forums and there were a bunch of roundabout ways that were still somewhat lacking in terms of security. I could try that message, but I was worried that some net trolls may try to put me into debt for fun. Still, it is worth a shot and I will see how it goes. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I checked into advanced variables, and this appears to be client-side; meant for including a user id or something that the end user doesn't want to change. After thinking about it, I'm not sure this is possible; once everything is said and done, the troll would still be sent to Paypal's site, with a donation amount included as a variable, and no coding or redirection on your site could change this. On the other hand, I'm more certain that Paypal will not charge you more than $0.01 to process a $0.01 donation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot for your help. I put the site up as is, with a little javascript alert to try to deter those that put less than $1. It can be bypassed easily, but I hope it will stop the average troll. I am glad to hear that about PayPal.

Comment: For your peace of mind, you might want to put through a $0.01 donation just to see what Paypal charges.

Comment: PayPal doesn't charge more than the total payment amount. However, it's yet frustrating that such a simple option as minimum amount is not provided.